# First order inseparable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a reaction kinetics homework, actually the homework is solved since the integrated equation is given, I want to derive myself the equation but I am struck. The reaction is just a simple isomerisation ($A\rightarrow B$). The initial concentration is just the sum of the isomers.

$$[A_0]=[A]+[B]$$
My problem arises at this differential equation, wich I am ashamed for that I cannot solve it.
$$\frac{d[A]}{dt}=-k[A]+k'[B]$$
We can now write:
$$\frac{d[A]}{dt}=-k[A]+k'([A_0]-[A])=-[A](k+k')+k'[A_0]$$
Now this is the part I am struck. I know we cant just separate easily this equation, at least to my knowledge. $[A_0]$ clearly is dependent on $[A]$ so it is lost for me. I can show my work if you please, but it is nonsense for sure since i just divided the whole right hand side and multiplied with $dt$.
The right solution for this equation is:
$$[A]=\frac{k'+ke^{-(k+k')t}}{k+k'}[A_0]$$

Can u please hint me to the right direction. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is $A_{0}$ actually dependent on $A$ i.e $A_{0}(A)$ or is $A_{0}$ a constant? If it is the latter, use an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations).

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed. Yes $A_0$ is a constant.